# XCode NSObject method error. Data cleared before method is returned

Tags: ios, xcode, return, automatic-ref-counting

I'm extremely new to iphone development so I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake.

I'm have a custom object that's a subclass of NSObject which includes a method that invokes the following method:

```
-(NSArray*)pageOutput:(NSString *)query page:(int)pagenumber
{
    // create the GET url string
    NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [urlString appendString:@"http://webpage.com/api.php?"];

    [urlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"query=%@&page=%i", query, pagenumber]];

    NSError *error;

    // request JSON response from server
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    return jsonArray;
}
```

While debugging I notice that the value of jsonArray is valid, and then something interesting happens. 
When I step through the debugger, I notice that the return statement is skipped over, I then step into the end '}' then finally returning to the return statement which was skipped over. 
Unfortunately, the final step clears all the declared values in the method and thus the return is always NULL.

I'm at a loss as to why this is occurring. I'm assuming it probably has to do with ARC. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

::EDIT::

Added the method that invokes the previous method. Name of the object is rdoSearch

```
-(id)initSearch:(NSString *)searchQuery page:(int)pagenumber
{
    self = [super self];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *localResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    rdoSearch *testSearch = [[rdoSearch alloc] init];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [testSearch pageOutput:searchQuery page:pagenumber];

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

    return self;    
}
```

:: EDIT #2 ::

I figured out how to fix the problem. I put all the code in this statement:

```
if (self) { }
```

Any reason as to why this fixes the problem?

Comment: I tried your code, using a different url, and it worked for me. How are you calling this method? Please show that code.

Comment: updated my question with the requested code.

Comment: I don't know if that causes your problem, but `self = [super self]` should probably be `self = [super init]`.

Comment: The problem might be that testSearch, being just a local variable, is being deallocated after the method finishes. Try making a property, for testSearch and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I ended up putting all my code into a "if (self) { }" statement and everything works. I'm not sure why... but it does. I did this for both initSearch and pageOutput.